# Input and Text-area won't lineup - CSS

Tags: html, css

I am practicing CSS and I can't lineup an input and textarea tag for a reply form.

[image: website]

```html
<form action="" method="">
  <input style="width: 50%;" type="text" class="" name="message_name" placeholder=" Your Name">
  <br>
  <textarea rows="3" cols="5" style="width: 50%;" name="message_comment" class="" placeholder=" Message"></textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: Can't tell. It just may be some kind of padding or margin. Set margin or padding to 0 and see what happens. And go from there.

Comment: The code you posted is not sufficient to reproduce the issue in your screenshot.

Comment: can you post your CSS too?

Comment: Please post the CSS

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if Im understanding your question at all.

```html
<form action="" method="">
  <input style="width: 50%; margin-bottom:10px;" type="text" class="" name="message_name" placeholder=" Your Name">
  <br>
  <textarea rows="3" cols="5" style="width: 50%;" name="message_comment" class="" placeholder=" Message"></textarea>
</form>
```